# Enabling Core Data syncing in iCloud only for OS X 10.8.x and iOS 6.x

Tags: core-data, icloud

I read everywhere that syncing a core data persistent store is pretty broken in versions of OS X earlier than 10.8 and iOS earlier than 6.0.

Since cloud syncing would be only a feature of my app, not a requirement, would it be feasible to use (in OS X's case) a 10.8 base SDK, a 10.7 development target and only use iCloud syncing features when running under 10.8?

I guess what I'm trying to make sure is that there isn't any statically linked stuff that would prevent this from working properly and using only non-broken code under 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

You do this kind of check by looking for features that you need which are only present in specific releases. In this case, check for something iCloud-related that was added in Mac OS X 10.8 / iOS 6.0. For example, the `ubiquityIdentityToken` method on `NSFileManager`:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] respondsToSelector:@selector(ubiquityIdentityToken)]) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
```

I'd describe iCloud with Core Data as "less broken" on 10.8 than on 10.7, but I wouldn't go so far as to recommend it. Still, if you want to use it, this is how you could check.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I should have been clearer with my question.

I'm good with finding a way to 'check'. I just wanted to make sure that if I do that, there's no way that some 10.7 code would be somehow statically linked with my app since my deployment target is 10.7.